# Splitting columns from an excel file and creating a list of elements

Tags: r, list

I have an excel file of 8 columns. The number of columns can change, so I need to write something able to work with a bigger number of columns too.

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | y | z | k | j | l | m | n |
| x | y | z | k | j | l | m | n |
| x | y | z | k | j | l | m | n |

I need to create a list in which each element is a new data table with the combination of different columns:

table1

| A | B | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | y | z | k |
| x | y | z | k |
| x | y | z | k |

table 2

| C | D | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | y | z | k |
| x | y | z | k |
| x | y | z | k |

Each table needs to be named with numbers, from 1 to n.
With this script:

```
excel_file<- read_csv("~/pathway.csv")
colnumbers<-1:8
colsplits<-split(colnumbers, ceiling(colnumbers/4))
purrr::iwalk(
  colsplits,
  ~ write.csv(excel_file[, .x], paste0(.y, ".csv"))
)
```

Unfortunately I obtain the wrong combination. It puts together columns ABCD and then EFGH, in a new list of data table named 1 and 2, as I want. Do you know how can I obtain he combination of ABEF and CDGH, and make it work also for an initial excel of let's say, 100 columns?

Comment: How are you determining the groups of columns? If you start with 8 columns as in this example, does this mean you want `combn(8,4)` (70) different combinations of columns?

Comment: The pattern is always the same. The total will be always divisible by 4. If I have ABCDEFGH, I want a new list with table 1 ABEF and table 2 with CDGH. If the initial file is bigger, let's say ABCDEFGHILMN, the new list will have table 1 ABGH, table 2 CDIL, table 3 EFMN. I don't know if it's worth it to split them in half, then combine them. Like if I have 100 columns, split them in two table of 50 and 50. Then the first two columns of the first table will go with the first two columns of the second one. I hope this is clear.

Comment: I see, that adds a lot of clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's solve this trick with looking at a vector first. Frankly, it does not matter what the values are, so long as we know that it is always divisible by 4, and we know that the first 2 from the front half pairs with the first 2 of the second half, etc.

Starting with length 12:

```r
vec <- LETTERS[1:12]
spl <- cumsum((seq_along(vec)-1) %% 2 == 0)
spl
#  [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6
split(vec, spl - ifelse(spl > max(spl)/2, max(spl)/2, 0))
# $`1`
# [1] "A" "B" "G" "H"
# $`2`
# [1] "C" "D" "I" "J"
# $`3`
# [1] "E" "F" "K" "L"
```

Demonstration with 8 and 16:

```r
vec <- LETTERS[1:8]
spl <- cumsum((seq_along(vec)-1) %% 2 == 0)
split(vec, spl - ifelse(spl > max(spl)/2, max(spl)/2, 0))
# $`1`
# [1] "A" "B" "E" "F"
# $`2`
# [1] "C" "D" "G" "H"
vec <- LETTERS[1:16]
spl <- cumsum((seq_along(vec)-1) %% 2 == 0)
split(vec, spl - ifelse(spl > max(spl)/2, max(spl)/2, 0))
# $`1`
# [1] "A" "B" "I" "J"
# $`2`
# [1] "C" "D" "K" "L"
# $`3`
# [1] "E" "F" "M" "N"
# $`4`
# [1] "G" "H" "O" "P"
```

How do we use this? Relatively simple:

```r
dat <- structure(list(A = c("x", "x", "x"), B = c("y", "y", "y"), C = c("z", "z", "z"), D = c("k", "k", "k"), E = c("j", "j", "j"), F = c("l", "l", "l"), G = c("m", "m", "m"), H = c("n", "n", "n")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
spl <- cumsum((seq_along(dat)-1) %% 2 == 0)
split.default(dat, spl - ifelse(spl > max(spl)/2, max(spl)/2, 0))
# $`1`
#   A B E F
# 1 x y j l
# 2 x y j l
# 3 x y j l
# $`2`
#   C D G H
# 1 z k m n
# 2 z k m n
# 3 z k m n

dat <- cbind(dat, data.frame(I=1:3, J=1:3, K=1:3, L=1:3))
spl <- cumsum((seq_along(dat)-1) %% 2 == 0)
split.default(dat, spl - ifelse(spl > max(spl)/2, max(spl)/2, 0))
# $`1`
#   A B G H
# 1 x y m n
# 2 x y m n
# 3 x y m n
# $`2`
#   C D I J
# 1 z k 1 1
# 2 z k 2 2
# 3 z k 3 3
# $`3`
#   E F K L
# 1 j l 1 1
# 2 j l 2 2
# 3 j l 3 3
```

Comment: This is clear, I am just wondering how can I apply this to my problem. There's an excel file with n columns. I need to split them in half and combine the first two of the first half with the first two of the second half and so on. Each group has to be a new data frame in a list. So the list will be composed of n:4 data table. First table containing 4 columns, second table containing 4 columns (second two of first half and second two of second half). Is this clear?

Comment: If you replace my `dat` with the frame you get from reading your spreadsheet, doesn't this work? It will create a list of frames as you described.

Comment: I solved it using a common value that is contained in the columns that I wanted to put together. Thank you so much anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is easy if we first `split` the indices into halves and create `interaction`s that we put in a suitable `matrix` where we `paste` together what belongs together. Finally we `strsplit` and `sort` to get our desired indices `{[1, 2, (n/2 + 1), (n/2 + 2)], [3, 4, (n/2 + 3), (n/2 + 4)], ..., [n/2 - 1, n/2, n - 1, n]}`.

```
f <- \(x) {
  h <- split(seq_along(x), rep(1:2, each=length(x)/2))
  ix <- strsplit(apply(matrix(interaction(h), 2), 2, paste, collapse='.'), '\\.')
  lapply(ix, \(j) x[sort(as.numeric(j))])
}
```

### Usage

```
f(openxlsx::read.xlsx('./dat8.xlsx'))  ## 8 cols
# [[1]]
#   A B E F
# 1 a b e f
# 2 a b e f
# 3 a b e f
# 
# [[2]]
#   C D G H
# 1 c d g h
# 2 c d g h
# 3 c d g h
```

```
f(openxlsx::read.xlsx('./dat20.xlsx'))  ## 20 cols
# [[1]]
#   A B K L
# 1 a b k l
# 2 a b k l
# 3 a b k l
# 
# [[2]]
#   C D M N
# 1 c d m n
# 2 c d m n
# 3 c d m n
# 
# [[3]]
#   E F O P
# 1 e f o p
# 2 e f o p
# 3 e f o p
# 
# [[4]]
#   G H Q R
# 1 g h q r
# 2 g h q r
# 3 g h q r
# 
# [[5]]
#   I J S T
# 1 i j s t
# 2 i j s t
# 3 i j s t
```

```
f(openxlsx::read.xlsx('./dat100.xlsx'))  ## 100 cols
# [[1]]
#   AA AB BY BZ
# 1 aa ab by bz
# 2 aa ab by bz
# 3 aa ab by bz
# 
# [[2]]
#   AC AD CA CB
# 1 ac ad ca cb
# 2 ac ad ca cb
# 3 ac ad ca cb
# 
# [[3]]
#   AE AF CC CD
# 1 ae af cc cd
# 2 ae af cc cd
# 3 ae af cc cd
# 
# [[4]]
#   AG AH CE CF
# 1 ag ah ce cf
# 2 ag ah ce cf
# 3 ag ah ce cf
# 
# [[5]]
#   AI AJ CG CH
# 1 ai aj cg ch
# 2 ai aj cg ch
# 3 ai aj cg ch
# 
# [[6]]
#   AK AL CI CJ
# 1 ak al ci cj
# 2 ak al ci cj
# 3 ak al ci cj
# 
# [[7]]
#   AM AN CK CL
# 1 am an ck cl
# 2 am an ck cl
# 3 am an ck cl
# 
# [[8]]
#   AO AP CM CN
# 1 ao ap cm cn
# 2 ao ap cm cn
# 3 ao ap cm cn
# 
# [[9]]
#   AQ AR CO CP
# 1 aq ar co cp
# 2 aq ar co cp
# 3 aq ar co cp
# 
# [[10]]
#   AS AT CQ CR
# 1 as at cq cr
# 2 as at cq cr
# 3 as at cq cr
# 
# [[11]]
#   AU AV CS CT
# 1 au av cs ct
# 2 au av cs ct
# 3 au av cs ct
# 
# [[12]]
#   AW AX CU CV
# 1 aw ax cu cv
# 2 aw ax cu cv
# 3 aw ax cu cv
# 
# [[13]]
#   AY AZ CW CX
# 1 ay az cw cx
# 2 ay az cw cx
# 3 ay az cw cx
# 
# [[14]]
#   BA BB CY CZ
# 1 ba bb cy cz
# 2 ba bb cy cz
# 3 ba bb cy cz
# 
# [[15]]
#   BC BD DA DB
# 1 bc bd da db
# 2 bc bd da db
# 3 bc bd da db
# 
# [[16]]
#   BE BF DC DD
# 1 be bf dc dd
# 2 be bf dc dd
# 3 be bf dc dd
# 
# [[17]]
#   BG BH DE DF
# 1 bg bh de df
# 2 bg bh de df
# 3 bg bh de df
# 
# [[18]]
#   BI BJ DG DH
# 1 bi bj dg dh
# 2 bi bj dg dh
# 3 bi bj dg dh
# 
# [[19]]
#   BK BL DI DJ
# 1 bk bl di dj
# 2 bk bl di dj
# 3 bk bl di dj
# 
# [[20]]
#   BM BN DK DL
# 1 bm bn dk dl
# 2 bm bn dk dl
# 3 bm bn dk dl
# 
# [[21]]
#   BO BP DM DN
# 1 bo bp dm dn
# 2 bo bp dm dn
# 3 bo bp dm dn
# 
# [[22]]
#   BQ BR DO DP
# 1 bq br do dp
# 2 bq br do dp
# 3 bq br do dp
# 
# [[23]]
#   BS BT DQ DR
# 1 bs bt dq dr
# 2 bs bt dq dr
# 3 bs bt dq dr
# 
# [[24]]
#   BU BV DS DT
# 1 bu bv ds dt
# 2 bu bv ds dt
# 3 bu bv ds dt
# 
# [[25]]
#   BW BX DU DV
# 1 bw bx du dv
# 2 bw bx du dv
# 3 bw bx du dv
```

---

Data:

```
openxlsx::write.xlsx(setNames(data.frame(matrix(letters[1:8], 3, 8, b=T)), LETTERS[1:8]), 'dat8.xlsx')
openxlsx::write.xlsx(setNames(data.frame(matrix(letters[1:20], 3, 20, b=T)), LETTERS[1:20]), 'dat20.xlsx')
openxlsx::write.xlsx(setNames(data.frame(matrix(apply(rev(expand.grid(letters, letters)[1:100, ]), 1, paste, collapse=''), 3, 100, b=T)), 
                              apply(rev(expand.grid(LETTERS, LETTERS)[1:100, ]), 1, paste, collapse='')), 'dat100.xlsx')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have to split them in groups of 4 in order. What I mean, not to 1234-5678, but 1256 and 3478. It's like splitting the columns into two groups then combining the first two columns of the first group to the first two columns of the second group, and so on.

Comment: @SaraAngelaGallarati Yess sorry I just noticed it, I am taking care of your problem right now!

Comment: @SaraAngelaGallarati Which type are your columns, are they all character, numeric, mixed?

Comment: They're all numeric. Thank you so much!

Comment: And each column has a different name, characters.

Comment: Thanks again but unfortunately this is not the structure. I will try to make this more clear. Assuming we have a table of 100 columns. We split them in half making two new tables, the first having columns from 1 to 50 and the second from 51 to 100. Column 1 and 2 from the first half should be in a new table with columns 51 and 52 from the second table (which are the first two of the second half). Column 3 and 4, with 53 and 54.

Comment: @SaraAngelaGallarati Hi, yesterday it was already a bit late here, but today I think I found a possible solution, please see update.